# How to give patterns to Simplify's assumptions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching

I'm trying to simplify an expression, and my guess would be like this:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[1 - Cos[θ]^2/sign[r Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]]^2], sign[_]^2 == 1]
```

Apparently, as I get unchanged expression back, `FullSimplify` doesn't understand what I mean. (`sign` is deliberately not a system `Sign` function here).

I do realize that I could simply switch to a replacement like `expr /. sign[_]^2 -> 1`, but I suppose in general simplification with a pattern could be more useful. E.g. when `sign[...]^n` would have `n==4` or whatever. Also in this case the rule I mentioned wouldn't work, since it should instead be `sign[_]^-2 -> 1` here.

So my question is: how do I use patterns in assumptions of `Simplify` family of functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this?

```
Power[sign[x_], n_?EvenQ] ^= 1;
FullSimplify[Sqrt[1 - Cos[θ]^2/sign[r Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]]^2]]
```

Answer (score 6):

A combination of [`TranformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TranformationFunctions.html) and [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html) (for the pattern matching) is useful here.

```
t[sign[x_]] ^:= 1

FullSimplify[Sqrt[1 - Cos[θ]^2/sign[r Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]]^2], 
 TransformationFunctions :> {Automatic, t}]   
(* Sqrt[Sin[θ]^2] *)
```

Comment: Not exactly. You are assuming that sign[x_] is always 1, but we need only even exponents, so a slight correction is needed `t[Power[sign[x_], n_?EvenQ]] := 1`