# How to assume that the sum of two functions is identically zero (independently from the chosen variables)?

Tags: functions, assumptions

I have met this problem and I do not know how to get rid of it. The problem is the following. I have defined a function h as sum of two functions f and g as follows:

`h[x_, y_] := f[x, y] + g[x, y];`

then, I have assumed that h is identically zero, that is,

`$Assumptions = h[x_, y_] == 0;`

Then, if I choose the variables, for instance,

`Simplify[h[x_, y_] /. x -> z];`

The output I obtain is

`0`

However, if I write

`Simplify[(h[x_, y_] /. x -> z) + 3]`

then the output is

`3 + f[z_, y_] + g[z_, y_]`

but I want 3 instead. In other words, I would like that any time the function h appears it is considered as equal to zero independently from the choice of the variables.

I really cannot understand why it does not work. I hope that someone can help me fix this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about adding the definition `h[x_,y_]=0`?

Comment: Related: [(42607)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42607), [(131515)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131515), [(141973)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141973)

Comment: Do you want to simplify `h[x_, y_] /. x -> z` or `h[x, y] /. x -> z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this does not answer your question, then treat it as a request for clarification.

I can't see what you are trying to accomplish with your code. If you are attempting to assume that `h` is identically zero for all variables, that is equivalent to defining

```
h[x_, y_] := 0
```

which would replace the previous definition

```
h[x_, y_] := f[x, y] + g[x, y]
```

rendering ir nor only irrelevant but null and void. To show this, let's do it in a local scope so that it doesn't affect your top-level definitions.

```
Block[{h},
  h[x_, y_] := f[x, y] + g[x, y]; 
  h[x_, y_] = 0; 
  h[u, v] + 3]
```

> `3`

Note that there is no need to introduce `Simplify`. Any call of `h` now evaluates to 0.

If your goal is to temporarily assume `h` is identically zero for the purpose of a specific evaluation, then `Block` is what you want. For example:

```
Block[{h},
  h[x_, y_] = 0;
  Sqrt[h[u, v]] + 3]
```

> `3`

#### Update

This discussion is added to address the clarification given by the OP in a comment to this answer.

If you require `f[x, y] + g[x, y]` "in the code, it put it equal to zero independently from the variables inside", you are mathematically requiring 
that $g \equiv -f$, so just write and evaluate

```
g[x_, y_] := -f[x, y]
```

Then

```
  1 + 3 f[x, y] + 2 g[x, y]
```

> ```
> 1 + f[x, y]
> ```

```
  1 + 2 f[x, y] + 3 g[x, y]
```

> ```
> 1 - f[x, y]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think my question is a little bit confusing. I try to explain it better. I would like that every time that I encounter an expression like f[x_,y_]+g[x_,y_] in the code, it put it equal to zero independently from the variables inside.